# Vue 3 createApp is not defined when import from entry file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to setup vue app using webpack.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "Shared/global": './ClientApp/src/js/Shared/global.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].entry.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: ""
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader }, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|woff(2)?|ttf|otf|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                  loader: "babel-loader",
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css"
        })
    ]
};
```

And this is the entry file:

```
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
const _ = require('lodash')
```

In my layout.html I call global.entry.js as such:

```
<body>
    <div id="layoutApp">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="module" src="/dist/js/Shared/global.entry.js" defer></script>
<script src="/ClientApp/src/js/Shared/layout.js" defer></script>
```

Then I try to use vue in layout.js:

```
const layoutApp = createApp({
    mounted(){
        console.log("layout is mounted VUE")
    },
});

layoutApp.mount("#layoutApp")

var array = [1];
var other = _.concat(array, 2, [3], [[4]]);
 
console.log(other);
```

But in chrome console it said createApp is not defined. But if I run only lodash code, lodash works fine. I cant figure out what I did wrong. Any help would be very helpful

Comment: you need to import it in the correct file (layout.js), lodash works because it's global, but your imports are not, they are just locally defined

Comment: Please, don't describe the error but post it as is, it matters. Currently it looks like a variable is really not defined, i.e. not declared. "But lodash works fine" - how do you know? The evaluation of layout.js stopped after the error. This isn't how JS modules work. You need to import things in every module you use them. It's a mistake to load /ClientApp/src/js/Shared/layout.js separately as native module, it should be a part of app bundle

Comment: If I import from layout.js it would be = import {createApp} from '../../node_modules/vue' instead of just import {createApp} from 'vue' right? That would expose the path

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm sorry but I have tested lodash by removing vue code in layout.js and it worked fine.

Comment: @EstusFlask I think I got what you said. Does it mean I need to include all client code in only 1 entry file? Does that mean for each page I need to import vue again? I'm trying to import vue globally

Comment: Yes. You can do this in many ways, but this one is the recommended one, otherwise you'll find yourself doing things that aren't explained much anywhere. It's unknown what "page" actually is in your case. If you have non-SPA website then you can have as many entry points as you need, with common things like Vue being shared between them, this is handled by Webpack chunking features. If you don't have a usable Webpack setup consider switching to Vue CLI or Vite which are basically setups that work out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on non-SPA website. It seems like the only way now is to create many entry points. I thought it was possible to just import vue in 1 entry point and then use it across all pages like calling vue with script tag in layout page then use it on other pages that share the same layout. I'll try to look on Vue CLI and Vite. Thanks @EstusFlask

Comment: Multiple pages presume that pages should differ. If they aren't then only 1 entry point is needed.